# Matching arrays in soapUI JSONPath RegEx Match assertions

Tags: json, regex, rest, soapui, jsonpath

I'm trying to make a JSONPath RegEx Match on SoapUI for the following Json Response:

```
{
   "quantidadeItens": 5,
   "registros":    [
            {
         "identificador": 1,
         "descricao": "Viagem à Disney"
      },
            {
         "identificador": 2,
         "descricao": "Carro"
      },
            {
         "identificador": 3,
         "descricao": "Smartphone novo"
      },
            {
         "identificador": 4,
         "descricao": "Casa nova"
      },
            {
         "identificador": 5,
         "descricao": "Apartamento Novo"
      }
   ]
}
```

On the attached Image we can see that the JsonPath is correct, but the SoapUI is not finding the match.

I guess that the [*] is not supported on SoapUI, but I didn't find anything about it on documentation.

[image: JsonPath Regex Match Configuration]

Comment: What is the expected output? Is it all `identificador` value list?

Comment: @rao. Yes. I want to assertthat all `identificador`values are numbers.

Comment: Is that a way to iterate on assertion's validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output of your JSONPath expression would be something like:

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5
]
```

This doesn't match your regex, but in any case soapUI produces `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, which the soapUI [documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/jsonpath-reference.html#notes-considerations) says is *not* a JSON array but just a list of values enclosed in square brackets.

So, a regex like `\[(\s?[0-9]+,?)*\s?\]` will match this output:

[image: regexmatch]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works. But, why should I use the \s? My value has no spaces.. I tried to take it off and doesn't work. Can you explain it to me, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `\s?` stands for 0 or one white space characters (space, tabs, line feeds, ...) in the output that soupUI produces from the JSONPath expression, rather than the values in your response message. Technically, the first `\s?` isn't required, but I included it so the regex matches both the vertical and horizontal outputs. In the soapUI documentation they say that they format their output inside square brackets, comma separated, with a space in between each data item.